# Pre-populating a multi stage form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form which is split over 4 separate screens, so the user is presented with screen 1, they fill out the fields and click Continue, then they are presented screen 2, they fill out those fields and click Continue, etc..

When they fill out the whole form, the details they have entered are written to a MySQL database.

They are allowed to go back through the form at any time and change the details....this is where I have a question.

When they navigate to screen 1, I read their previous details from the database and pre-fill the form with those values.

So far, so good.

When they click Continue, the form is submitted and we load screen 2. At this point, I have to read the database again to get the values they previously entered on screen 2.

I should mention here the I'm using an MVC pattern so each screen is a separate request.
I really like being able to split each screen in to a separate request as it keeps the HTML and controller logic nice and clean, but I'm starting to wonder if it's the best way to create a multi stage form!

What would be the best way to handle this need to retrieve the data at each screen? The only thing I can think of is to read the data at screen 1, and then store it in a session variable, but am I gaining much by doing that?

Should I even be bothered about having to keep re-reading the same data? It's not going to be a massive performance issue, but it just feels wrong to keep re-reading the same data.

Comment: After thinking some more about this, I think the answer will be to read the database at screen 1, then draw all the fields for screens 2, 3 & 4 as hidden fields on screen 1. The rest should hopefully take care of itself. I'll post back here later whether this is a good solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as I thought, was to read the database on screen 1 and write screen 2, 3 & 4 fields as hidden fields on screen 1.

This way, when screen 2 is being drawn, I check to see if there are any values in $_POST.

Same applies for screen 3 & 4.